# sync.Once implementation

Tags: go, synchronization

I have a question about ***sync.Once()*** in Go 1.12. The source code is below:

```
// Because no call to Do returns until the one call to f returns, if f causes
// Do to be called, it will deadlock.

func (o *Once) Do(f func()) {
    if atomic.LoadUint32(&o.done) == 1 {
        return
    }
    // Slow-path.
    o.m.Lock()
    defer o.m.Unlock()
    if o.done == 0 {
        defer atomic.StoreUint32(&o.done, 1)
        f()
    }
}
```

Why not just use an `uint32` variable, then do CAS on this variable. It seems to be more effective, and will not lead to deadlock.

The code like:

```
type Once uint32
func (o *Once) Do(f func()) {
    if atomic.CompareAndSwapUint32((*uint32)(o), 0, 1) {
        f()
    }
}
```

Comment: The code actually _does_ _use_ a uint32 and it _does_ _not_ deadlock. So what is your question?

Comment: we can use only a uint32，drop the Mutex，like the code snippet I gave above.And it will not lead to deadlock,if f calls Do again @Volker

Comment: Probably something to ask to golang-dev@googlegroups.com. The mailing list of golang contributors.

Comment: The potential deadlock is a feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`Once.Do()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Once.Do) does not return until `f()` has been executed once. Which means if multiple goroutines call `Once.Do()` concurrently, `f()` will be executed once of course, but all calls will wait until `f()` completes (they will be blocked).

Your proposed solution does not have this very important property! Yours only guarantees that `f()` will be executed only once, but if called from multiple goroutines concurrently, subsequent calls will return immediately, even if `f()` is still running.

When we use `sync.Once`, we rely on this behavior, we rely on `f()` being completed after `Once.Do()` returns, so we can use all variables that `f()` initialized safely, without having a race condition.